# Inno Setup: Can you add a NOT case to CloseApplicationsFilter?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an inno setup installer script that already handles closing one of the applications in use (that runs in the system tray) as part of `ssInstall` using old V5 ANSI version.  With V6 version the restart manager support wants warn that it's open and will close it.

I found the `CloseApplicationsFilter` value that can be used in `[setup]` but I want the inverse case, I want to tell it which NOT to include (exclude just one .exe) otherwise handle all the other files as normal.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Instead, you might use a preprocessor to generate a list of files you want to check.

Comment: Well, I changed it to close the item in `PrepareToInstall()` instead of `CurStepChanged() CurStep = ssInstall` then set a flag that it was running, turned off if normal process starts it, should it be canceled early then `DeinitializeSetup()` starts it if flag is still on.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer.